# How do I import Notes from my iMac to my iPad?

Tags: icloud, imac

Notes from my iMac do not appear on my iPad or iPhone, what could be wrong?

Comment: OK...how are you syncing your iPhone and iPad? What version of iOS is in use on the devices? What versions of OS X and iTunes are you using? Are you syncing with a cable or wirelessly? Do you have iCloud set up to sync notes?

Comment: I synch wirelessly. Yosemite10.10.1 on imac. iTunes is 12.1.2.27 on iMac. iPhone is iOS 7.1.2. iCloud preferences on iMac show a check mark to the left of Notes

Comment: When I sign into iCloud itself and open settings to see Notes, notes that I have written from Notes on my Mac and which still appear appear as notes on my Mac do not show up in the Notes app that appears in iCloud itself. Hope that makes sense. Thanks for whatever help.

Answer (score 1):

This is most easily done through iCloud, which should be the same account you sign in to the App Store with.

Go to System Preferences > iCloud. If you haven't already set up your iCloud account on your Mac, simply click on iCloud, and enter the username and password.

In the right side field, scroll down to "Notes" and tick the checkbox next to it. You may need to wait 5 or so minutes for iCloud to update.

On your iPad and iPhone, go to Settings > iCloud, scroll down to Notes and turn on the slider.

For additional setup info: 
https://www.apple.com/icloud/setup/mac.html

Comment: Thanks.  Hmm. When I open system preferences on my imac and then open Notes, the box next to Notes has been checked.  HOWEVER, when I go onto iCloud itself and open settings to see Notes, notes that I have written from Notes on my Mac and which still appear appear as notes on my Mac do not show up in the Notes app that appears in iCloud it self. Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

The **Notes** Application on the Mac has local (on the Mac only) *and* iCloud notes.

[image: Folders List]

On the **Menu Bar** click **View > Show Folders List** if it is hidden.  If you have iCould set up, you should see 2 Lists: One for iCloud, the other called **On My Mac**.

You can drag individual Notes (not the folder) from the Notes On My Mac to the Notes list on iCloud.  Then you should be able to see/edit them on your iOS devices.

[image: Notes App]